# Implementing a node-based graphical interface?

Tags: python, user-interface, directed-graph

I would like to implement a nodal-interface, basically a [DAG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) where each node performs an operation on it's input connections, and outputs something (which you can connect to another node)

Some example applications:

- [Apples "Shake"](http://www.apple.com/shake/) - [screenshot](http://images.apple.com/es/shake/images/index_hero.jpg)
- [The Foundrys "Nuke"](http://www.thefoundry.co.uk/pkg_overview.aspx?ui=CBC2593A-2C9F-4EF9-84BE-C198B0171453) - [screenshot](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/5a/Nuke_screenshot.png)
- [MindNode](http://www.mindnode.com/) -  [screenshot](http://www.mindnode.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2007/12/mn-screen-2.png)
- [vvvv](http://vvvv.org/) - [screenshots](http://vvvv.org/tiki-index.php?page=screenshots)
- [Quartz Composer](http://developer.apple.com/graphicsimaging/quartz/quartzcomposer.html) - [screenshot](http://img24.imageshack.us/img24/8969/quartzcomposer.png)

---

As a first goal, I would like to have an *graphical application* with only 2 nodes. A "number" which simply outputs a fixed number, and an "Add" node, which takes two inputs and outputs the sum of the two.

As people have answered so-far, I have a rough idea of how to represent the data in code, for example in Python'y looking pseudo-code:

```
class Number:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def eval(self):
        return self.value

class Add:
    def __init__(self, input1, input2):
        self.input1 = input1
        self.input2 = input2

    def eval(self):
        return self.input1.eval() + self.input2.eval()


a = Number(20)
b = Number(72)

adder = Add(a, b)
print adder.eval()
```

How would I got about wrapping a custom GUI around this? Something like the following, but slightly less hand-drawn!

[image: nodal UI mockup]

Where would I begin? I currently plan to write it in Objective-C/Cocoa, although I'm more than open to suggestions for other languages.

Answer (score 3):

I would start by modelling some basic interfaces (in the OOP sense, not the GUI sense). Seems to me you'll have a Node which will accept a collection of inputs and a single output. You didn't give any indication of how broad the data types are, but you'll want some suitable method of representing your inputs/outputs. For your first goal, this could be an integer.

In some generic C style OOP language (hope it makes sense):

```
class Node<T> {
    Node<T>[] inputs;
    T eval();
}

class AdderNode extends Node<int> {
    int eval() {
        int accum = 0;
        for (inputs : i)
            accum += i.eval();
        return i;
    }
}

class ConstNode<int I> extends Node<int> {
    int eval() { return I; }
}

AdderNode a;
a.inputs.add(ConstNode<2>());
a.inputs.add(ConstNode<3>());
a.eval();
```

You could expand on this by replacing int with some abstract class, generic, or interface. Actual implementation will vary based on the actual language, of course.

Answer (score 2):

I would start with modeling the interesting operations. Ultimately you will connect them to a UI, but that is the steering wheel and gas pedal, not the engine.

What you are attempting to build has a lot in common with programming languages: variables, values, types, expressions, evaluation, etc. Many of the metaphors are applicable and might provide some guidance.

If you are using .NET 3.5, you have the option of [Expression Trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx), which allow you to represent and compile code expressions at runtime.

For example, to model your first goal:

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;

ConstantExpression theNumber2 = Expression.Constant(2);
ConstantExpression theNumber3 = Expression.Constant(3);

BinaryExpression add2And3 = Expression.Add(theNumber2, theNumber3);
```

To invoke the expression, we need to wrap `add2And3` with a method. This is done with a lambda expression:

```
Expression<Func<int>> add2And3Lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<int>>(add2And3);
```

`Func<int>` represents a method which takes no parameters and returns an `int`. In C#, the code represented by `add2And3Lambda` would be:

```
() => 2 + 3
```

So what we have is an expression tree whose root is a method. Because a method is *callable*, we can compile the tree into an instance of the underlying delegate type:

```
Func<int> add2And3Func = add2And3Lambda.Compile();
```

Now we can invoke the code we built:

```
int theNumber5 = add2And3Func();
```

Every expression available to .NET languages is supported.

Imagine every node in your graph has an `Expression` associated with it. That might give you an idea of the power of expression trees and how they could help you with this task.

Answer (score 1):

All that node systems have in common that they describe a functional programming language. A function takes multiple parameters and returns a single result, no matter for what purpose it was designed. Some examples:

- Graphics: Blur(Image, Kernel, Radius) -> Image
- Math: Add(Number, Number) -> Number
- Relational: Filter(Table, Predicate) -> Table

Basically that comes down to a function signature like `Func<object[], object>` (C#).

You will face the question of how to make your node system persistent. Do you want to make the result of a node usable as parameter by only one other node (tree) or by multiple nodes (graph)?

Example of a tree, directly have the parameters a child nodes:

```
Add(
  Multiply(
    Constant(5),
    Constant(4)
  ),
  Multiply(
    Constant(5),
    Constant(3)
  )
)
```

Example of a graph, store all nodes in a list and only use references:

```
A := Constant(5)
B := Constant(4)
C := Constant(3)

D := Func(Multiply, A, B)
E := Func(Multiply, A, C)

F := Func(Add, D, E)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found some useful information on implementing such an interface in Cocoa:

- [Intro to Quartz](http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/intro_to_quartz/) and [Intro to Quartz II](http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/intro_to_quartz_two/) - describes basic drawing in an NSView
- [FlowChartView](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?FlowChartView) on Cocoadev - pretty much what I was looking for, an implementation of the Quartz Composer interface.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this thread while researching for a similar solution.
Recently I found a nice project on github https://github.com/nodebox/nodebox
which seems to be exactly what you are looking for. At least one could extract and adopt the editor components from the project.

Regards,
Stephan

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, thanks for wanting to contribute but answers with links only are discouraged. Please review the [answering guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). A good rule of thumb is to look at your answer without the link and if it provides little to no value, consider expanding.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [bwise](http://wiki.tcl.tk/8537) has something of interest?

On the bottom half of [this page](http://wiki.tcl.tk/9219) shows an example of using bwise to create a multiplication block that takes two numbers as an input.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a Execution Graph like you describe in this project:
[GRSFramework](http://gabyx.github.io/GRSFramework/)

The source code can be found [here](https://github.com/gabyx/GRSFramework/tree/master/common/include/GRSF/logic).

Currently I am working on releasing a better, cleaned version of this system in the project [ExecutionGraph](https://github.com/gabyx/ExecutionGraph).
It might be of interest for you as well.

Then there is also the TensorFlow library from Google which has a similar system implemented [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/)